# How to connect to Glue catalog from an EMR spark-submit step

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-glue, amazon-emr

We use pyspark in an EMR cluster to run queries against our glue database. We use two methods to execute the python scripts namely through a Zeppelin notebook and through EMR steps. Connecting to the glue database works greats in Zeppelin, but not in EMR steps. When we run a query against the glue database, we get the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Database '{glue_database_name}' does not exist.
```

This is the spark configuration used in the executed .py file:

```
spark = SparkSession\
.builder\
.appName("dfp.sln.kunderelation.work")\
.config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "36000")\
.config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")\
.config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")\
.config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")\
.config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.ignoreDataLocality.enabled", "true")
```

The step is submitted using boto3 with the following configuration:

```
    response = emr_client.add_job_flow_steps(
        JobFlowId=cluster_id,
        Steps=[
            {   'Name': name,
                'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
                'HadoopJarStep': {
                    'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                    'Args': ['spark-submit', '--deploy-mode', 'client', '--master', 'yarn', "{path to .py script}"]
                }
            },
        ]
    )
```

Both types of EC2 users have been given glue and s3 privileges.

What do we need to setup to connect to the glue database?

Comment: Does anything in these docs help? I assume you've seen it, but want to put it here if anyone face similar issues as you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html

Comment: Yes, I have tried following this guide to no avail.